# Фильтр количества товаров в категории Opencart

Tags: php, opencart

Привет,

Подскажите, где правится фильтр количества товаров в категории?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нигде не могу найти :(. Вывод 12, 25, 50, 100. А мне нужно добавить "Все". И можно ли это реализовать?

Нашел, что это модуль "`OC Layered Navigation`", правда могу и ошибаться, но вопрос, где поправить остатся.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: "...но вопрос, где поправить остатся." - Что Вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: Тут ошибся, это не тот модуль.

Comment: Хотя у плагина `OC Layered Navigation` тоже есть такая же строчка кода. Наверное для пагинации создана. `$limits = array_unique(array($this->config->get($this->config->get('config_theme') . '_product_limit'), 25, 50, 75, 100));`

Answer (score 1):

Лимиты можете поправить в контроллере category.php, ищите такую строчку:

```
$limits = array_unique(array($this->config->get($this->config->get('config_theme') . '_product_limit'), 25, 50, 75, 100));
```

Реализация же необходимой вам логики "все товары" без использования сторонних модулей предусматривает использование специалиста с последующей оплатой проделанных модификаций.